# unable to load a file from local file system to hadoop file system

Tags: linux, docker

I was trying to add a file from linux file system to hadoop file system using hadoop fs -put source_file_path destination_file_path i am running hadoop using docker(cloudera container) but it is showing file not found.

As i am running hadoop on docker container do i need to follow other way?

below is the code

```
# hadoop fs -put /home/teja/ALR.csv /tmp
```

I am getting this error:-

```
put: /home/teja/ALR.csv': No such file or directory
```

I am new to hadoop.Am i doing any wrong? but the file(ALR.csv) is present in /home/teja directory can anyone provide me the correct solution how to load a file from linux file system to hadoop file system that is running on docker container.

Comment: Is the file `/home/teja/ALR.csv` in that location in the Docker container?

Comment: The Cloudera docker container doesn't have a `teja` user, so how would it have a home folder for it? More specifically, prove to us it exists - `cat /home/teja/ALR.csv`, from the container, not your host. Removed hadoop tags since it's only Unix issue

Comment: Alternatively, install hdfs cli outside of Docker. If you're new to that, then you don't need to use it